# iTextSharp stamper wraps text

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to fill in some stamper AcroFields.

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Title", "Lipsum");
```

I created the pdf in illustrator and the form fields with Adobe Acrobat X Pro. The problem is that although the text fields are the width of the page, in the saved pdf the text wraps at about 1 third of the width.

Another question would be if it's possible the have the textfield autoSize in height, or a way to handle the overflow of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I'd like to see that PDF.  I suspect the fields aren't as wide as you think they are.

2) You can set a field's font size to zero to enable "auto sizing", which works both within Reader and iText.  However, it sizes to the actual field size, not what you think it might be.

I'm guessing you drew a spiffy form field background in Illustrator, then put a field over it in Acrobat Pro, but didn't size the field width to match the spiffy illustrator background.  Could be wrong, but that's my hunch.

---

That's the flattened PDF.  Can I see the original with the form field still intact?  Sorry I wasn't more specific.  None the less, I can learn a little from reading this PDF:

Looking at the bounding boxes for the flattened field XObject and it's internal clipping rectangle, it looks like it should be using most of the page:

The page is ~600 points wide by ~850 tall.
The flattened field XObject is ~560 points wide by ~100 tall.

I wonder if there's some non-standard carriage return characters in your text that iText picks up on by Acrobat does not...

Anyway, I'd like to see the unflattened PDF.  Filled in is good, but not flattened.

---

Okay, looked at the template.  I don't see anything that would cause the line breaking you're seeing... which makes me think my second guess was right: new line characters.

Looking at the text layout code might give me a hint.  Each of your lines of text goes like this (for example):

```
1 0 0 1 2 88.24 Tm  0 g (Die Semmerrolle der l{e4}nge nach zu einer grossen Roulade)Tj
```

- n n n n n n Tm: text matrix
- g: gray (0 g: black)
- (...)Tj: show text

That's consistent with the code path when you set a text field value in the trunk of iText (and the most recent release[s]).  That code (ColumnText) is quite good at breaking text properly, and used all over the place.  The bounding box is correct (as shown in a couple places of the flattened PDF).

Check your input.

Comment: Mark, thank you for your answer and for this invaluable library! I tried to make a print screen to better show the issue: http://img638.imageshack.us/f/schermafbeelding2011033.png/ In the top area there's the selected form field where the text from below goes. Also, I forgot to mention that if I fill in the field manually then the text wraps exactly where it's supposed to.

Comment: That shoots down my "it's not really that wide" theory.  Can I see the (filled) PDF itself?

Comment: You can get the test pdf from here http://www.2shared.com/document/KeXkcyqa/test1.html

Comment: That's the flattened PDF.  Can I see the original with the form field still intact?  Sorry I wasn't more specific.